# Sanity.io - problem with google authentication

Tags: google-oauth, sanity

I currently encounter this problem toward the end of the google authentication step.
Request error while attempting to reach https://afjo9y1e.api.sanity.io/v2023-06-12/data/mutate/production?returnIds=true&returnDocuments=true&visibility=sync
at xhr.onerror (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:52654:13)
I have double check and my dataset is correct, my token and projectId are also correct. Can someone tell me what the problem can be?

```
login.jsx
import React from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { FcGoogle } from 'react-icons/fc';
import shareVideo from '../assets/share.mp4';
import logo from '../assets/logowhite.png';
import { GoogleLogin, useGoogleOneTapLogin, googleLogout } from '@react-oauth/google';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

import { client } from '../client';

const Login = () => {

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const responseGoogle = (response) => {
    var profileObj = jwt_decode(response.credential);
    const { name, sub, imageUrl } = profileObj;
    const doc = {
      _id: sub,
      _type: 'user',
      userName: name,
      image: imageUrl,
    };
    client.createIfNotExists(doc).then(() => {
      navigate('/', { replace: true });
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className='flex justify-start items-center flex-col h-screen'>
      <div className='relative w-full h-full'>
        <video 
        src={shareVideo}
        type='video/mp4'
        muted
        autoPlay
        loop
        controls={false}
        className='w-full h-full object-cover'
        />

        <div className='absolute flex flex-col justify-center items-center top-0 bottom-0 left-0 right-0 bg-blackOverlay'>
        <div className='p-5'>
            <img src={logo} width='130px' alt='logo' />
          </div>
          <GoogleLogin
            onSuccess={responseGoogle}
            onFailure={responseGoogle}
        />;
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login

client.js
import sanityClient, { createClient } from '@sanity/client';
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url';

export const client = createClient({
  projectId: 'afjo9y1e',
  dataset: 'production',
  apiVersion: '2023-06-12',
  useCdn: true,
  token: 'skJkL8ysz4K3Dundey4RLF3XjC87xnqoaDbxHmNcaJfjT3tceDkAeSvVjDN7nreqYWYZ1naG8Ij978eCyuCa6iWIyGVCV7sG9TgZQBVc9qOCmytdI6fuwfi2e0eHlguyRIFjn2irOSVLa0AYbhBaTt57okMMkCLKjU1mc0ilR2qVRploGr4H',
});

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);

export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);

App.js 
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './components/login';
import Home from './container/Home';
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId="207995127249-vpk23f1fqpun1h2i7m0goivdnvojlhrs.apps.googleusercontent.com">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/*" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </GoogleOAuthProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I double check everything from dataset to token to projectId, everything is correct but it still doesn't work

Comment: is there an error? whats the problem exactly